# How to get statistics for all accounts(active and inactive)?

Tags: google-ads-api

At the moment I am getting stats this way:

```
    $adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())->fromFile($this->account->token)->withOAuth2Credential($this->oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();
    $managedCustomerService = $adWordsServices->get(
        $session,
        ManagedCustomerService::class
    );

    // Create selector.
    $selector = new Selector();
    $selector->setFields(['CustomerId', 'Name']);
    $selector->setOrdering([new OrderBy('CustomerId', SortOrder::ASCENDING)]);
    $selector->setPaging(new Paging(0, 100));
```

but how to get statistics for all accounts **active and inactive**? This code returns only list of active accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunately not possible to retrieve statistics for inactive / cancelled accounts.

You'll either receive a `AuthorizationError.CUSTOMER_NOT_ENABLED` error (in the Ads API) or a `AuthorizationError.CUSTOMER_NOT_ACTIVE` (in the Adwords API).